# How to Access External List Data via Code?

Tags: external-list

Any suggestions would be helpful...

I am attemting to access an external list using the Server OM. The external list is configured to use pass through credentials. The list functions perfectly in the SharePoint UI.

When I run this code in a console app:

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://DOM-dev.DOM.net/sites/plm"))
            {
                SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                SPServiceContextScope contextScope = new SPServiceContextScope(context);

                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {


                    SPList list = web.Lists["Industries"];
                    Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
                    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
                    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item["Industry"].ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
```

I get this error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled   Message=Attempted
>   to perform an unauthorized operation.   Source=Microsoft.SharePoint
>   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.CheckUserIsAuthorized(SPBasePermissions
>   perms)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetFilteredEntityInstances(XmlDocument
>   xdQueryView, Boolean fFormatDates, Boolean fUTCToLocal, String
>   firstRowId, Boolean fBackwardsPaging, String& bdcidFirstRow, String&
>   bdcidNextPageRow, List`1& lstColumnNames, Dictionary`2&
>   dictColumnsUsed, List`1& mapRowOrdering, List`1& lstEntityData)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureEntityDataViewAndOrdering(String&
>   bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageFirstRow)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEntityInstanceEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()
>          at TestExternalList.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\rkauche\Desktop\IT\TestExternalList\TestExternalList\Program.cs:line
>   28
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dmitry Kaloshin of LightningTools whose team member, Phill Duffy, created [BCS Tester Man](http://bcstesterman.codeplex.com/), assisted me in getting this right.

As I suspected the issue was with attempting to use Pass Through authentication on the BCS data source. I had attempted to use the Secure Store Application for impersonation but had issues with it because I had set it to individual rather than group. Once I reviewed [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/01/27/setting-up-bcs-with-secure-store-application-impersonation.aspx) as suggested by Dmitry Kaloshin and saw that the author had set it to "Group" I deleted all of my lists, my settings for the SSA. and started from scratch. After recreating all the settings on the SSA, ECTs, and External List it all worked like a charm.

This was not an ideal solution for me, though. I really did not want to deal with the fact that now every user interacts with the database as the Secure Store user. But I suppose that is life.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the double hop issue...

Comment: I have Kerberos auth enabled. It's not a double hop issue.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, and it sounds as though it does not in this case, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer. This does not help a user who is unaware of the double hop issue. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: If it were the double hop issue the list would not work in the SharePoint UI. This issue seems related to the fact that the BCS datasource is using Pass Through authentication. I am attempting to work through some other problems, but I believe I have solved it.